# Converting 8 bit audio signal to lower enconding

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

I am confused with an assignment question given to us. The question reads as follows "Use 16bit,8bit,4bit,2bit,1bit to represent the speech signal at 8KHz sampling,Observe the speech quality and waveform differences in each case and note down the com ments.". So now I have looked at few audio recording tools and even tried various audio recording APIs in MATLAB but the least number bits used in them is 8bits. So if i want to convert them to 4 bit or lowers, how can I do it. Do i have to manually for loop and change the elements of the matrix or can I get a tool. (note: This is just an introductory course we not expected to know too much about these things. And more over this the first assignment)

Comment: You don't need to reduce the *actual* number of bits, just quantise the audio to the required levels. So just take some 16 bit audio and quantise it appropriately to simulate 8, 4, 2, 1 bit audio.

Comment: If this is an online course, I am sure it will be fine to ask such a question in the forums there. As long as you don't ask for the solution, discussions about problems you face are usually welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The intuition you need, is to appreciate the meaning of bit shifting.  Lets say you begin with a 16 bit number - here the universe of possible values is 2^16 which means you can have 65536 different values, possibly from 0 up to 65536 - 1, or from say -32768 to +32767   Now if the input signal you are processing ostensibly can vary from -1 through 0 up to +1 (standard audio signal) this audio curve is free to map onto those 65536, so -1 could map to -32768 and +1 to 32767 - If we only have 8 bits to represent our signal as it varies from -1 to +1, 2^8 === 256 possible values, here we could map -1 to -128 and +1 to 128.  Similar mappings for 4 bit, 2 bit ...

Now to implement this using bit shifting, if you start with a 16 bit representation and need to transform this into 8 bit you simply discard the least significant bit positions by shifting the 16 bit number to the right by 8 bits :

```
intout = bitshift(A,k)
```

returns A shifted to the left by k bits, equivalent to multiplying by 2k. Negative values of k correspond to shifting bits right.  So if variable A is our 16 bit integer and for k we use -8 this will implement the bit shift we need to translate a 16 bit number into its 8 bit integer equivalent.  By now you might have guessed as we progressively lower the bit depth from 16 to 8 to ... our resolution decreases and this will be perceived audibly as sound with less depth and loss of subtlety and nuance until finally at bit 1 which can only vary from 0 to 1 the audio will have become sumarily unintelligible - I hope this helps